# Android JNI method - Is the second parameter jclass or jobject?

Tags: android-ndk

Folks,

In my Android Java code, I have a declaration as follows:

```
public class SurfacePanelNative extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
   ...
   private static native void native_render();
}
```

In my native code, I have the function declared as:

```
void native_render(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaSurface) {
   ANativeWindow* window = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, javaSurface);
   ...
}
```

Looking at some examples on the net, it appears that the function should be declared as:

```
void native_render(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
   ...
}
```

I am wondering which declaration is the right one.

I am thinking the first one is the right one. Otherwise, I don't have enough information to obtain javaSurface.

I would appreciate it if someone can shed some light on this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 12):

It is `jclass` if the method is `static`, otherwise `jobject`. If you use `javah`, as the JNI designers intended, you will always get the right answer.

Comment: @Peter is this the correct answer? It's not accepted.

Comment: @Phi Yes is correct. The OP is generally not the best judge.