# How to call ndk function on MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have managed to compile the following code and I would like to know if it is well and that you give me an example of how to call the compressor function in the MainActivity of android.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include<Principal.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL 
JAVA_com_pfc_camera_ndkmain_MainActivity_compresion(JNIEnv* env,jobjectArray 
 jargv){


 //jargv is a Java array of Java strings
 int argc = env->GetArrayLength(jargv);
 typedef char *pchar;
 pchar *argv = new pchar[argc];
 int i;
for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
{
    jstring js = (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement(jargv, i); //A Java string
    const char *pjc = env->GetStringUTFChars(js,NULL); //A pointer to a Java-managed char buffer
    size_t jslen = strlen(pjc);
    argv[i] = new char[jslen+1]; //Extra char for the terminating null
    strcpy(argv[i], pjc); //Copy to *our* buffer. We could omit that, but IMHO this is cleaner. Also, const correctness.
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(js, pjc);
}

//Call main

Principal *pa=Principal::CreateInstance(argc,argv);
pa->Run();
pa->FreeInstance();

//main(argc, argv);

//Now free the array
for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
    delete [] argv[i];
delete [] argv;

return 0;


}
```

Comment: The title does not match what you are asking ...

Comment: sorry my english is not well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the Java side to call the C side of your code.
But I think your C code is missing the `jclass` argument.
You should use `javah` to create the .h file containing the erasure of the native function. See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html).

The Java side should look like this:

```
package com.pfc.camera.ndkmain;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    native int compression(String[] argv);

    public int foo(String[] args) {
        return compression(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use the jclass argument?

Comment: Usually you do not use it except if you need to reference your java class or instance for C side (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861801/android-jni-method-is-the-second-parameter-jclass-or-jobject)